# Is there a way i can loop coin prices from FTX, i am getting error

Tags: python

**I want to get the values when i run the code by looping them but i am getting errors**

```
key = 'https://ftx.com/api/markets'

currencies = ['BNB', 'AVAX', 'DOT', 'LTC', 'BCH']

# base_currency = 'ETH'
quote_currency = 'USD'


for i in currencies:
    url = key + currencies
    data = requests.get(url)
    data = data.json()
    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(url).json()
df1['result']
```

**And i am getting errors when i output it**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d4cc3a7de331> in <module>
      7 
      8 for i in currencies:
----> 9     url = key + currencies
     10     data = requests.get(url)
     11     data = data.json()

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Comment: What do you think a valid URL would look like for the BNB 'currency'?

Comment: 'https://ftx.com/api/markets/BNB/USD'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to construct the URL with its 3 component parts - i.e., the base URL, currency and quote currency. Always a good idea to do some validation.

```
import requests
import json

currencies = ['BNB', 'AVAX', 'DOT', 'LTC', 'BCH']
quote_currency = 'USD'
url = 'https://ftx.com/api/markets'

for currency in currencies:
    api = f'{url}/{currency}/{quote_currency}'
    try:
        (r := requests.get(api)).raise_for_status()
        if (j := r.json()).get('success'):
            print(json.dumps(j['result'], indent=2))
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        print(f'{api} -> {e}')
```

**Note:**

Requires Python 3.8+